# Video Gallery Web Developement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a website and am trying to finish off my video page. I want to have a layout like this:
[image]

with one big video placeholder at the top and several thumbnails underneath.

When you click on the thumbnails below I want them to load the related video in the space up top. I'm comfortable with the html/css needed to design something like this but not knowledgeable enough to write the php or javascript (not sure what I would need?). What would be a way to go about doing this? I've googled for over half an hour trying to find a solution but searching for video galleries just comes up with a lot of wordpress plugins which I would rather not use.

Anyway, I would be grateful for any advice.

edit: If it makes any difference, I will be embedding youtube videos, not self hosted ones

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: I'm not so concerned with finding the perfect way, any method at all would be helpful for me at the moment because aside from a wordpress plugin (tubepress) which has a monthly charge I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: @TomF have a look at the videos page at http://wwww.vicchesnuttrelief.com  It's not exactly the same but you'll get a good idea

Comment: What are you using to store data about the videos? Are they hard-coded or stored dynamical on some back end. The approach I would use for the small tiles would be to store all the required info needed for the main video i.e. src, title and description etc as data values. Then create an onlick event for the class associated with the small tiles get the data values using data or attr methods and then set the attribute values on the big div. Would probably just wan the video src value.

Comment: if my answer helped you, mark it checked/green.

Answer (score 2):

here you go

Demo: http://codepen.io/techsin/full/EjrqVz/

Code at: http://codepen.io/techsin/pen/EjrqVz

```
$('#vids .thumb').click(function(){
  $('#mainVid video').attr('src',$(this).data('url')).get(0).play() 
});
```

Video element comes with play method by default it's a native api. So to run a video, all you have to do is invoke method play on video element.

In my code i have jquery selector, i get the native element using `get` and then call native method `play`. Jquery doesn't have play for playing videos or sounds method as of now.

The way whole things works is I basically replace the src url of video element and tell it to play. Just like how i would change image without changing the image element itself. That's by changing the src url.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and quickest way would be to use the youtube embed code from youtube and then swap the src attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/zs90on6r/

HTML

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tXoyQssMwMM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<a class="another" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mKCRPJcOp90">Time Travel Stories</a>
<a class="another" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o_JZbQao6jo">Skate</a>
```

Javascript (witch jQuery):

```
$(".another").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
})
```

Comment: You can add the autoplay attribute to the url if you want them to play automatically